# How can I make the Edit the related item menu show in Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor, security, permissions

I am setting permissions for content editors of a site. The user in question is a member of the following roles:

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
- sitecore\Author
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Social Authoring
- sitecore\Analytics Testing
- sitecore\Analytics Personalization
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing

When this user logs in to Experience Editor and clicks the `More` option of a component's properties, the `Edit the related item` option is not shown.
See the screenshot.

[image: Component More menu regular user]

However, if I log in with a user that has the Administrator checkbox set on their "User Profile" then this option is visible.

[image: Component More menu admin user]

What security setting should I change to make the `Edit the related item` visible for a non-administrator user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this menu option to show the user must have read access to the `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common Field Buttons/Edit related item` item in the `Core` database or be a member of the `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing` Role.

Answer (score 2):

Create them under: /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons and you'll be able to edit specific section of the component. Its in Core database.

To check what permissions navigate to /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit, there will be a list of granted permissions. The most granted is Client Developing, the least Authoring.
Here is the snapshot [image: List of granted roles]

Bear in mind that those roles [image: List of roles won't have this button available] are restricted to see that button.